# Laravel: Why does eager loading only keep results for last model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1, eager-loading

If I execute the following:

```
App\Assignment::with(['unit.records' => function ($q) {
                    $q->where('process_date', '>=', '2016-01-01')
                        ->where('process_date', '<=', '2018-09-27')
                        ->orderBy('process_date')
                        ->orderBy('process_hour')
                        ->limit(1);
                    }])
                    ->whereIn('id', [9])
                    ->get();
```

Then I get the following result:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1104
 all: [
   App\Assignment {#1112
     id: 9,
     unit_id: 6,
     start_date: "2015-11-25",
     end_date: "2016-01-04",
     unit: App\Unit {#986
       id: 6,
       records: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#945
         all: [
           App\Record {#853
             id: 6624,
             unit_id: 6,
             process_date: "2017-09-19",
             process_hour: 14,
           },
         ],
       },
     },
   },
 ],
}
```

Note how the loaded unit has a record that matches the query.

Now, if I use the exact same query but add another assignment (49) to my `whereIn` array:

```
App\Assignment::with(['unit.records' => function ($q) {
                    $q->where('process_date', '>=', '2016-01-01')
                        ->where('process_date', '<=', '2018-09-27')
                        ->orderBy('process_date')
                        ->orderBy('process_hour')
                        ->limit(1);
                    }])
                    ->whereIn('id', [9,49])
                    ->get();
```

The record for assignment 49 is shown, but the record for assignment 9 does not show up anymore:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1032
 all: [
   App\Assignment {#1014
     id: 9,
     unit_id: 6,
     start_date: "2015-11-25",
     end_date: "2016-01-04",
     unit: App\Unit {#1283
       id: 6,
       records: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1254
         all: [],
       },
     },
   },
   App\Assignment {#1061
     id: 49,
     unit_id: 29,
     start_date: "2017-02-24",
     end_date: "9999-12-31",
     unit: App\Unit {#1279
       id: 29,
       records: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1131
         all: [
           App\Record {#1284
             id: 6062,
             unit_id: 29,
             process_date: "2017-03-10",
             process_hour: 13,
           },
         ],
       },
     },
   },
 ],
}
```

The record that matches the criteria for assignment 9 obviously exists, but for some reason it doesn't get loaded when the query finds more than one assignment with a unit/record that matches the criteria.

I tested this with more assignments as well, and in each case the record will only show up for the last assignment in the array.

What's the deal here?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you use:

```
->limit(1)
```

This limits number of relationships records to 1. Just remove this line and it will be fine.

Comment: I need to limit the results because there are a very large amount of records that fit my query and I can't store them all in memory, and I only need the first one anyways. Is there a way to limit results per relation rather than across all relations?

Comment: @samalamma708 There is no easy way. How many records do you expect to have for `App\Assignment` ? You showed for example  `->whereIn('id', [9,49])`. How big would be this array? You can also take a look at https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18014

Comment: There will be 100s of assignments each with potentially 1000s of records

Comment: @samalamma708 So you need to first find the query to get those results (unit records) and then you can try to set relationship for Assignment. As far as I know you cannot do it using relationship unless you don't use solution provided in the github link

Answer (score 3):

There is no native support for eager loading with a limit in Laravel.

I created a package for it: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

Use the `HasEagerLimit` trait in both the parent and the related model.

```php
class Unit extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
}

class Record extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
}
```

Then you can apply `->limit(1)` to your relationship and you get the expected result.